# Is it possible to share a Google Calendar so that only people with the URL can see it (but no login required)?

Tags: google-calendar

I want to create a calendar for a private organization. I want everyone to be able to see the calendar without a loggin but don't want the calendar to be "public" (searchable).

I.e., accessible/viewable only if you have the link.

I looked at the Google Calendar settings and the closes they have is a private iCal link, but then these people would need to know how to add that to their calendar and that's probably too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google Calendar, you can send your calendar link to any email/ email-group and no log-in is required to access that calendar.

You can do it by following these steps:

**1.Open google calendar.**

[image]

**2. In calendar list right click required calendar and select open send to friend.**

[image]

**3. Send it required mailing group.** 
[image]

All recipients of mail will get a link in email & able to browse on any internet browser & no log-in is required.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is there a company-wide email alias for your company? If so, you can try sharing the Calendar to "View" events only.

In this way the HTML link you send *should* allow them to view the events associated with this calendar.